# Stream content of an XML node using Axiom

Tags: java, axiom

I have an `InputStream` that contains XML, that contains content that is escaped XML. The Escaped XML can be hundreds of Megabytes in size so it must be processed as its own XML document to prevent Apache Axiom's OMElement from loading the whole content into memory.

Is it possible, using Axiom, to stream the content of the node and parse it as a separate document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this in Axiom is to call `getTextAsStream` (with `cache` set to `false`) on the `OMElement` that wraps the escaped XML, then parse the returned `Reader` as XML. Note that this only works if you tell Axiom to disable coalescing in the underlying XML parser, as described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIOM-478?focusedCommentId=15089009&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15089009); if you don't do this, then the entire content would still be loaded into memory.

Comment: I just saw this now since I was out  with the family over the long weekend. I will give it a try and review your answer/edit my question once I come back with some results. Thank you so much Andreas!

Comment: Thanks @Andreas-Veithen, This was exactly what I needed.